# Deploying Angular App to Firebase Hosting Github Actions

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, github-actions

I'm trying to use Github actions to deploy my Angular app to Firebase hosting. I'm using [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-firebase) action in order to accomplish this. My `release.yml` file looks like the following:

```
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  firebase-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: actions/setup-node@master
      with:
        node-version: '14.x'
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build --prod
    - uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
      with:
        args: deploy --only hosting
      env:
        FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

However when I commit this onto the `master` branch, I get the following error:

> Error: Must supply either "site" or "target" in each "hosting" config.

I have no clue what this error means, so any help would be great. Thanks!

---

Edit: My firebase.json looks like the following:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "public": "MyName",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "projectName",
      "public": "dist/projectName",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple hosting sites?  You need to specify deployment target in your firebase.json.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets#configure_your_firebasejson_file_to_use_deploy_targets

Comment: See me edited answer @cwlau

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed the issue by just simply removing the second section of hosting turning this:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "public": "MyName",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "projectName",
      "public": "dist/projectName",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

into the following:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "projectName",
      "public": "dist/projectName",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure if there is any side effects to do this, but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly! Thanks!